# Make modification and decide where to put an element before his creation - using angularjs with directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to detect the creation of an element (an new added element) and do an action on this element (modification) and decide where to put it.

The element is added by an anguler biding items and I use a new directive:

My page HTML:

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <main style="overflow: hidden;">
    <input type="text" ng-model="url" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? addItem(url) : null" class="form-control" id="myinputurl" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Type URL">

    <section class="cd-section index cd-selected">
      <p>My section</p>
      <content-item ng-repeat="item in items" itemActive="{{item.active}}" type="section"></content-item>

    </section>
    <!-- section -->

  </main>

  <nav class="cd-nav-container" id="cd-nav">

    <p>My list</p>
    <ul class="cd-nav">

      <content-item ng-repeat="item in items" itemActive="{{item.active}}" type="list"></content-item>


    </ul>
    <!-- nav -->
  </nav>

</body>
```

Add the item in a items scope:

```
 $scope.addItem = function(myurl) {

var lastChildId = $("ul li").length;
var vall = lastChildId + 1;
var idItem = "item" + vall;

angular.forEach($scope.items, function(p) {
  p.active = false; //set them all to false
});

//var trustedUrl = trustSrc(myurl);

$scope.items.push({
  id: idItem,
  item: '<a id="' + idItem + '" href="' + myurl + '"> Test for StackOverFlow </a>',
  active: true
});
```

}

My directive:

```
     app.directive('contentItem', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: false,
    template: function(elem, attr) {

      var template = 'ErrorFail';

      var type = attr.type;

      if (type === "section") {
        if (attr.itemActive) {
          template = '{{item.itemm}}';

        }
      } else {
        template = '<li id="{{item.id}}" color="red">{{item.itemm}}</li>';

      }
    return template;
    }

  }
});
```

Can someone help me please ?? This is [Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/rWsG759kNWGPVcgaP5By?p=preview)

Comment: first of all why do you need jQuery to do this? Should be letting angular generate the DOM based on model data. Next there is no `<section>` shown in html and last where are you calling this from and where are those variables defined?

Comment: Could you show us a demo on JSFiddle or plnkr? It's difficult to know what you're trying to accomplish by reading the post.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is: Before creating an element, decide where to put it depending of some conditions.

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear.